# Input with type "date" doesn't display new value

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-input

I have an input with type "date":

```
<input type="date" value="2016-08-16"/>
```

When I load the page I can see that specified date is selected. [image]

However, if I try to select another date - 11 August 2016, for example - value in the input is not updating and is always 08/16/2016.

I'm testing page in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit). Do I miss something in element declaration?

Comment: This might be informative: [Datepicker does not update input field upon selecting date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461193/jquery-datepicker-does-not-update-input-field-upon-selecting-date)

Comment: Hi @showdev Thank you for the link. I understand that "value" attribute of the input will not be updated if you check it with web-inspector. However I expect that value displayed on the page - and visible to user - should have value that you just selected.

Comment: Ok, I see. Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce that issue.

Comment: *if I try to select another date* -- How?  How are you selecting another date?  Programmatically, or through the control?

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle input value with a variable.

```js
let inputDate = "2021-06-18";

const handleChange = (event) => {
  inputDate = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" value=inputDate onChange={handleChange} />
```